# Can I call an object from `for` loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, glob

e.g:

```
path = 'sresize/*.*'

for a, source in enumerate(glob.glob(path)):
    print(a, source)
    img = cv2.imread(source)
```

can I call the `img` as an object outside the `for` loop? If it doesn't, is there any way to generate the images from a directory and then call it as an object? except for the `ImageDataGenerator`.
Thank you for your worthwhile information :)

Answer (score 1):

As it is now, you get the last `img` that was read in if you use `img`.

You want to store the objects in a list or a dictionary so that you can call them later.

```py
path = 'sresize/*.*'

imgs = {}
for a, source in enumerate(glob.glob(path)):
    print(a, source)
    imgs[a] = cv2.imread(source)
```

Then call the fist one with `img[0]`, the next would be `img[1]`, etc..

Answer (score 0):

```
path = 'sresize/*.*'
images = []
for a, source in enumerate(glob.glob(path)):
    print(a, source)
    images.append(cv2.imread(source))
```

If you declare variable before a for loop, the variable doesn't get harvested by garbage collector in the for loop 100% in any language.

Comment: While this is true, variables defined in a loop are also not deleted

Comment: To use array, you have to define it, and it's hard to do in loop and results in unnecessary check for it's definition to not set it empty again.

Comment: OK, so what? Also, that isn't an array, but a *list*. And `list` objects don't have a `.push` method. Neither do arrays. Note, Python doesn't *have* variable declarations. It sounds like you are confusing things with javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Yes because the only variables that python deletes from memory once a for loop is done running are the ones that are defined as part of the loop. So in your case the last values of a and source won't be available

Comment: "the only variables that python deletes from memory once a for loop is done running are the ones that are defined as part of the loop." That's not how it works at all. Python does not have block scope.